# Notification only if Firebasedata is updated

Tags: android, firebase, notifications, firebase-realtime-database

In my application I try to call Notifications with the following code:

```
 ref.orderByChild("uid").equalTo(uid).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
 public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Long number = dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount();
            if (number == 0){
            // no updates
            return;
            }
            else {
                showNotification();
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    });
```

My problem is that Notifications are shown although there are no Updates in my Firebase-Database (especially for the retrieved Data). Why is the ValueEventListener running so often and how can I solve my issue? The 'number' is always the number of all assigned books from the logged-in User...
Maybe there is another smarter solution to get push-notifitcations.

Comment: Look into Cloud Functions for Firebase to send a message to users when something in the database changes.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of addvalueeventlistener() use  addListenerForSingleValueEvent